# how to access a return value in php from mysql function

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am using a msql function as follows.

```
CREATE  FUNCTION `check_login`(p_username VARCHAR(30),p_password VARCHAR(30),role VARCHAR(20)) 
RETURNS BOOL
deterministic
    BEGIN
    DECLARE retval INT;
    Declare cid int;
            IF role = "customer" THEN

                select convert(p_username,unsigned integer)into cid;
                SELECT COUNT(custid) INTO retval FROM customer WHERE custid = cid and pwd = p_password;
                IF retval != 0 THEN
                    RETURN TRUE;    
                ELSE
                    RETURN FALSE;                           
                END IF;
            END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And using the following php code.

```
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
$role=$_POST['role'];
$sql="select check_login('$myusername','$mypassword','$role')";
$result=mysql_query($con, $sql);
$row=mysql_result($row,1);
echo $row[1];
```

But am unable to get the return value.

Comment: **NOTE:** Your stored function is not really `DETERMINISTIC`.

Comment: You use PDO, prepared statements and bindValue() method of the prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another comment, you should use a different MySQL adapter (PDO or mysqli). However, if you must keep the adapter as is, you should change "mysql_result($row, 1)" to "mysql_result($row, 0)," as the results of a query are indexed starting from zero. Alternatively, you could assign a name to the derived column and use "mysql_fetch_assoc" to return an associative array.

Answer (score -2):

```php
$sql = 'SELECT check_login(\'$myusername\', \'$mypassword\', \'$role\')';

$vars = array(
   '$myusername' => $_POST['myusername'],
   '$mypassword' => $_POST['mypassword'],
   '$role' => $_POST['role']
);

$queryResult = $conn->query(strtr($sql, $vars));

$return = $queryResult->fetch_assoc();

foreach ($return as $return=> $functionReturn) {
   $return = $functionReturn;
}

echo $return;
```